# How to save the selected choice/answer of a questionnaire as a string in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create a questionnaire in Xcode using swift (tableview) where the user of the app can choose their preferred choice (for example one question can be, what days are you available? and the user has a list of options to choose from and can select multiple)

To do this, I have created a variable called potans (short for potential answers) and another variable called selectedans which holds the information regarding the selected answers.

When the user clicks one of the answers, a checkmark appears next to the selected choice and also the row number of the selected answer is printed. When the user again clicks on the already selected option, they automatically deselect it and the checkmark is removed and the row number of the deselected row is again printed.

I would like to be able to store the selected answer/s when the user presses the 'next button'. However, since the user can change their mind (select and then deselect) and can select multiple answers, I do not know how to convert the information of row number to the string name.

So when the user presses (refer to the code I have written) ans1, a checkmark appears and row:0 is printed (output). If the user does not do anything else and presses the 'next button' everything is alright. However, if the user deselects ans1 (we get another row:0 printed) and then selected ans2 and ans3 (where we then get row:1 and row:2 printed), so what line of code would I need to add to be able to conclude that the final answers of the user have been ans2 and ans3?

I had thought of somehow making two of the same row numbers (either consecutively or not) cancel out but I do not know how to do that.

```
var potans = ["ans1", "ans2", "ans3", "ans4", "ans5"]

var selectedans:[String] = []

//some irrelevant code here

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return potans.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = potans[indexPath.row]
    let selectedView = UIView()
    selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.65, green:0.85, blue:0.62, alpha:1.0)
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView

    return cell

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType == .checkmark
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    } else {

        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }

    selectedans.append(potans[indexPath.row])

    print("row: \(indexPath.row)")
}

//Created a 'next' button going to the next question

@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)

}
```

Right now, the output is just the row numbers that are selected AND deselected. In reality, I would like an output that shows the final row number/s, disregarding the selected and then deselected answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:)` method of `UITableViewDelegate` and delete related data in your `selectedans` array in this method.